# Estimate memory usage of an image on Android

Tags: android, image, memory

Is there some quick way to estimate what the memory usage of a bitmap will be in an Android app based on resolution, compression type etc. without having to actually build and run an app with the image to find out?

Comment: Have you read: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html#read-bitmap

Comment: @MorrisonChang Yes.  I've even implemented it.  But I'd like a shorthand rule of thumb to be able to estimate memory impact without having to write code to find out.  It seems there'd be some way to do that.

Comment: Still not sure what you are asking - if you know the size of the bitmap and the quality - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.Config.html#RGB_565 - most likely ARGB_8888 you know how big the bitmap will be (w*h*4 bytes) or are you referring to writing out a file in jpg/png/webp and knowing the size?

Comment: @MorrisonChang Actually you just provided what I was looking for "most likely ARGB_8888 you know how big the bitmap will be (w*h*4 bytes)".  That let me to [all the ways pixel information is stored on android](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.Config.html).  If you provide this information in the form of an answer, I'll accept it, if you want the points.